# Why isn't git bash transforming the path to *nix notation for my python installation?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, git-bash, mintty

Working on Windows 7, I've installed git with the git bash and then installed python and am having trouble running it from the command line. Here's what I've learned so far:

1. *nix uses `:` as a path separator.
2. Therefore `C:/Users/Someone` would be seen as two separate paths.
3. *nix uses `/c/users/someone` notation instead.
4. When I run `echo $PATH` from git bash, every path there (including Node, which I only just installed now, after everything else) is using the correct `/c/` notation--
5. --except Python, which still has the `C:/` notation, and is therefore not accessible from the terminal since it can't find it.
6. When I go to Environment Variables and check the path from the os's perspective, they are of course *all* in `C:/` notation.

How, where, and/or why is git bash converting all of them to its own notation *except* python? How can I fix this?

Here is `PATH` as seen in Environment Variables in Windows Advanced Settings:

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\; C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Here it is as seen from git bash:

```
/c/Users/Aerovistae/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Aerovistae/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon: C:/Users/Aerovistae/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32:/c/Users/Aerovistae/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

You can see near the end that Python is the only one with the wrong notation.

Comment: Are you talking about what Python sees as the value of `PATH`, or are you talking about the value of `PYTHONPATH` as opposed to `PATH`?

Comment: I understand that he is seeing the PATH environment variable as seen from Bash being malformed. Maybe there is something in your ~/.bashrc wrongly incrementing your PATH?

Comment: I have not created a .bashrc. @MarkReed I am talking about the value of `PATH` that *bash* sees. I am unable to run python from bash because of it. Really not clear why I'm getting downvotes on this one.

Comment: Random thought: perhaps Python used forward slashes instead of backslashes when it added itself to PATH?  (Why is this tagged Linux?) (Please post the value of PATH as seen by Windows.)

Comment: Nope, backslashes. I tagged linux because it's sort of a clash between a linux program and the windows OS, and I thought knowledge from either side could potentially be relevant.

Comment: The entry in the PATH for Python has a stray leading space.  That seems likely to be the culprit.

Comment: I was sure you were right, but I fixed it with no result. Same value of `PATH` in bash.

Comment: Do you mean the same value *except* that the extra space has disappeared?  (If the space is still there in the bash version, that indicates that the change didn't kick in.  You might need to reboot.).

Comment: You win. Fixed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new CMD, and set the minimal PATH you need:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;%PATH%
```

(Make sure `python.exe` is indeed in `C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32`)

Then, type `bash`, and see if `python.exe` works.

You can also add your previous paths, to identify the one causing trouble.
In the OP's case, the stray leading space for the Python path was the troublemaker.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, which it must be, but aren't you setting `PATH` three times, just overwriting the previous value each time?

Comment: @Aerovistae no: I first reset `PATH`, then I add other paths in front of the `PATH`: `set PATH=xxx;%PATH%`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Which I assume is informative somehow. But of course this  in of itself has no effect on a newly opened git bash window.

Comment: @Aerovistae could you try and set your environment variable PATH to the value defined in this answer, and open a new CMD in which you type `git bash`? Then a new git bash Windows would benefit from that PATH and from python.

Comment: You're saying don't use the git bash icon, set the env var then use CMD and type bash instead of bothering with this strange error?

Comment: @Aerovistae you can use the git bash icon, provided your user or system environment variable `PATH` is set as I described: then all your shortcuts (like the git bash icon) will inherit that `PATH`, in which `python` will be working.

Comment: Any idea why this value of PATH would work when the original value didn't?

Comment: Not sure, which is why I always recommend to simplify the PATH first, then add back the other original paths one by one, to identify the one causing problem.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to also point out that any stray leading spaces will cause this problem? Then I can accept your answer without remorse with all relevant info included. It turns out that the space before `C:\ `  for the python path was causing the problem.