# Running Python through Powershell or Git Bash

Tags: python, windows, powershell, terminal, git-bash

I will preface this with, I know questions like this have been asked, but I feel as I can't find my answer.

My question is this: I downloaded Python about 2 months ago to begin learning it. I just recently starting trying to use the terminal more and would like to move forward using it a lot for commits and package installs.

Unfortunately I am having a very hard time getting Python to run properly through either Git Bash or Windows Powershell. I think i may have moved files around too much before even starting with using the terminal and now I'm not sure what's correct.

Should I uninstall and re-install?

I am on Windows 10, any advice onhow to organize my files properly so everything can run correctly. I would also like to be able to open my text editor from the terminal, PyCharm or Atom.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have Python in your environment variables?

Comment: I have lots of different paths setup for it, I think from reading so many things. Could it be that I have too many and they are confusing one another?

Answer (score 1):

Try first to simplified your PATH (as [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41529917/6309)) in a CMD session.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;%PATH%
```

Once you have the right path, you can replicate it in your user environment variables.

(replace `C:\Users\Aerovistae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32` by your own Python2 installation path)

Then type `bash` and check python does work.